# How to add numbers to top of histogram bars?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to add the frequency number above each bar and want to keep the bars separated. I can't figure out how to keep the bars separated.
My code is:

```
df_dm2["resolution"].plot(kind='hist', color='blue', edgecolor='black', linewidth=1.2 )
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.xlabel('Resolution (m)')
plt.title('Region DM2 Frame Resolution Frequency')
#plt.text( .92, 3.5, r'$\mu=1.092531 ,\ \sigma=0.091098$')
#plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 2, 0.2))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 200,25))
plt.savefig('histogram_dm2.png',dpi=72, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

My output thus far is as follows: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsbYx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `rwidth` option in `plot`:

```
df_dm2["resolution"].plot(kind='hist', 
                          color='blue', 
                          edgecolor='black', 
                          linewidth=1.2,
                          rwidth=0.75)
```